# How to extract only 2 values in dataframe column per row where each value is separated by a ',' in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a df (reference image) that I create that shows an aggregation of all the combinations each publisher has to another and then does calculations based on said pair(s). [image]

I want to pull every distinct pair that only contains 2 publishers and all the other field values that are tied to that pair (example would be Amazon, CBS but twice since there is one for month 10 and one for month 11 and so on.

How do I extract this or apply some dplyr function to only pull those? Was thinking of using a regex function in with a pipe but not sure how to do it.

## Expected output

```
Publisher    |   month_grp
Amazon, CBS       10
Amazon, CBS       11
Amazon, CW        10
Amazon, CW        11
Amazon, ESPN      10
Amazon, ESPN      11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want the rows with just one comma in the publishers column. You can get these using

```
df[grep('^[^,]+,[^,]+$', df$publishers),]
```

UPDATE:  Based on a refinement of the question in the comments.

If you want to get rows that have either one or two publishers, you can use:

```
df[grep('^[^,]+(,[^,]+)?$', df$publishers),]
```

Enclosing the `,[^,]+` part in `(   )?` makes it optional, so this will get rows with either one or two publishers.

Comment: I like the elegant detectors here using `^,` to negate commas in publisher names!

Comment: Do I need to close the grep with another ')'? @G5W

Comment: Ugh  yes.  I will fix the answer.

Comment: @G5W is there a way to update this to pull everything up to the first ,? So get all individual publishers as well as what you submitted before which pulls 2? So all single and pairings in the publisher column?

Comment: Yes,  I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to one posted seconds ago, but with `dplyr::filter` and `stringr::str_detect`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~ Publisher,            ~month_grp,
        "AWS, CBS",             4,
        "AWS, CBS, CW",         2,
        "AWS, ESPN",            6,
        "AWS, CBS, ESPN",       2,
        "AWS, Samsung TV plus", 4,
        "AWS, ESPN, CBS",       4
        ) |> 
  filter(str_detect(Publisher, "^[\\w ]*, [\\w ]*$"))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Publisher            month_grp
#>   <chr>                    <dbl>
#> 1 AWS, CBS                     4
#> 2 AWS, ESPN                    6
#> 3 AWS, Samsung TV plus         4
```